# What is the minimal ammount of code I need for using django-cms-search 0.2.6?

Tags: django, django-haystack, django-cms, xapian

I want to use django-cms-search in my project and have installed it together with xapian and the xapian_backend. In my settings file, I have defined `HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE`, `HAYSTACK_SITECONF` and `HAYSTACK_XAPIAN_PATH` (because the django system is a bit old). Furthermore, I've included haystack.urls and created a corresponding template.

The index is not created when I run `manage.py update_index`.

Is it necessary to put any code into code into `HAYSTACK_SITECONF`?

The [docs](http://django-cms-search.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#usage) suggest that I sould create a models.py file in the directory defined in HAYSTACK_SITECONF and put this code into it:

```
from cms_search.cms_app import HaystackSearchApphook
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
apphook_pool.register(HaystackSearchApphook)
```

But this has no effect.

Comment: Did you solve it? Or did you find some examples than standard doc? I'm using haystack+whoosh. It's so difficult to find explanatory code!

Comment: @Daviddd I couldn't find anything, but meanwhile we've created our own package using whoosh that should be simple to install and extend [here](https://github.com/nomad5000/django-easy-search).